# DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges EF6 results in System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the context has changed

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

After migrating to Entity Framework 6 I get an error when executing unit tests on the build server.

I'm using the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer. When I change it to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` everything works, but I want to stick with the former initializer.

The error I'm getting is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   The model backing the 'AppContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)..

Which is correct, it changed, but with `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer, it should be recreated. Any ideas?

EF is configured in App.config. Here's the relevant part:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=my.app.unittest;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <contexts>
        <context type="my.app.core.Data.AppContext, my.app.core">
            <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1[[my.app.core.Data.AppContext, my.app.core]], EntityFramework" />
        </context>
    </contexts>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Write your code for database configuration and how you initalize the database.

Comment: I've updated the question with config info. Hope it's enough

Comment: IF you change it to DropCreateDatabaseAlways its working?

Comment: The problem if the migration file not in sync with the database then you can never create the database; what is your migration kind magic ? or no magic

Comment: If I change it to DropCreateDatabaseAlways it's NOT working. The migration is mostly automatic, but that's not the case. DropCreateDatabaseAlways should drop the database if it's not in sync with the model, instead I get the error.

Comment: Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>()); Set this line code before you create the Context if this working! then he got the wrong configuration if not than the problem in your migration

Comment: Nope, it's not that. Setting the initializer in code instead of the config changes nothing (checked). 
I dropped the db manually, it was recreated. We'll see if the next time the model changes the problem reappears

Comment: Chris just change it now add something in any entity and check it out. and check your migration history always automatic?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with a (derived) DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer. My tests were working earlier this morning against the EF 6 release candidate. This looks like a new change in the final build.

Comment: I haven't found a fix yet, but discovered something: my (non-test) context uses EF Migrations, and my tests are picking up the DbMigrationsConfiguration (which only has AutomaticMigrationsEnabled=false in the constructor). If I *exclude* the DbMigrationsConfiguration from my project and re-run the tests, they pass. Including it again will make them fail.

Comment: Stefan, I don't have a configuration - I'm running on defaults, but this problem that we're encountering is most probably related to the fact that the defaults for migrations changed in EF6 - I remember reading about it somewhere, just don't remember exactly what it was :/

Comment: @Stefan, have you found a fix for that? I have exactly the same issue than you

Comment: @SebastianPiu, no. I worked around it by making my DbContext abstract. My solution (posted below) is almost exactly the same as yours. I think this is a late EF design decision we're going to have to live with.

Answer (score 19):

Well, it looks like EF 6.0 introduces a new rule:

"If the DbContext is using an Initializer AND Migrations are configured, throw an exception when building the model".

Up to and including the EF 6 RC this wasn't enforced. The annoying part is that "Migrations are configured" is defined by the implementation of a DbMigrationsConfiguration. There doesn't appear to be a way to programmatically disable Migrations in tests - if you implemented

I worked around it in a way very similar to Sebastian Piu - I had to get rid of the Configuration class from my tests, but I couldn't just remove it because we're using Migrations for our main project. Argh!

This was my code before:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbDContext, IMyDbContext
{
  public IDbSet<Users> Users {get; set;}
  public IDbSet<Widgets> Widgets {get; set;}
}

// Migrations are considered configured for MyDbContext because this class implementation exists.
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
  public Configuration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
  }
}

// Declaring (and elsewhere registering) this DB initializer of type MyDbContext - but a DbMigrationsConfiguration already exists for that type.
public class TestDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context) { }
}
```

I encountered the System.InvalidOperationException when the DbContext was being initialized in my test code. Since the application doesn't use any Initializer, there were no problems running the app as before. This only broke my tests.

The solution (which feels more like a workaround to things missing from EF) is to segment the Initializer and DbMigrationsConfiguration so only one is seen in a runtime environment. I want my tests to use the Initializer and I want my application to use the DbMigrationsConfiguration. This could be done more cleanly if DbContext had an interface, but alas it only implements IObjectContextAdapter.

First I made my DbContext abstract:

```
public abstract class MyDbContextBase : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
      public IDbSet<Users> Users {get; set;}
      public IDbSet<Widgets> Widgets {get; set;}
}
```

Then I derived 2 classes:

```
public class MyDbContext : MyDbContextBase
{
  public MyDbContext(string connectionStringOrName, IDatabaseInitializer<MyDbContext> dbInitializer) 
    : base(connectionStringOrName)
  {
  }
}

public class MyTestDbContext : MyDbContextBase
{
  public MyTestDbContext(string connectionStringOrName, IDatabaseInitializer<MyDbContext> dbInitializer) 
    : base(connectionStringOrName)
  {
    Database.SetInitializer(dbInitializer);
  }
}
```

Both a MyDbContext and a MyTestDbContext are IMyDbContexts, so your existing dependency injection setup should work without requiring changes. I only tested Spring.NET.

My DbMigrationsConfiguration implements the derived type that is NOT used by tests:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
  public Configuration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
  }
}
```

Finally, the initializer's type was moved to the derived test class type:

```
public class TestDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyTestDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyTestDbContext context) { }
}
```

I can confirm my tests are passing and my application (and Migrations) is still working as before.

Comment: I'm wondering how this work, for me, `Database.SetInitializer(dbInitializer);` is static, therefor I'm unable to follow this through. Any Ideas?

Comment: That's correct, SetInitializer is a static method on System.Data.Entity.Database (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.113).aspx). What part isn't working for you?

Comment: Thank you, saved my week. Tried everything else for PostgreSQL. On SqlServer I had no problem on default scenario for EF6 db initialization.

Answer (score 5):

I found the same issue just after upgrading to EF6. After reading Stefan´s comment and having the same symptoms as he describes (tests were loading the Configuration class from my main project)

Solution/workaround in my case was to

- create new `class TestContext: MyDataContext` in my Tests project
- change the initialiser from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDataContext>` to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestContext>`
- update/generalise places where I created my *real* context to use the test one

I could do this because most of my tests just extend from a PersistenceTest class, so I understand this might be a pain to change if you have a big catalog. So looking forward to other solutions

Answer (score 3):

This is throwing because you have migrations enabled and you are using the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer.  Entityframework does not support using this initializer with migrations.  You have two options:

- Disable the initializer

or

- Disable migrations by removing the migrations configuration

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this behavior was intended. Here's a quote from one of the developers:

> This change of behavior was by design because EF5 would create the database without using the defined migrations meaning that the database created by the initializer could be different to the one created by Migrations. This could lead to testing against one database schema but running in production against a different database schema. However, we have tentatively decided to make a change to this behavior and this is being tracked here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1709

Answer (score 1):

What works fine for me is excluding the migrations using `define`. Here is how:

- Create a new configuration called `Test` that defines `TEST`
- In your tests, throw an error when `TEST` is not defined.
- Exclude your migrations when `TEST` is defined:

```
#if !TEST
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
{
    //...
}
#endif
```

You might need to exclude all of your migrations, which isn't totally satisfying either (but I haven't tried it because I don't have any migrations yet).