# DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to set up an initializer used in a test environment. From everything I read, **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges** is exactly what I need. Often times the database gets slightly out of sync with the model, and I need to simply start over fresh.

So here is how I went about setting up my context constructor

```
public ApplicationContext(int dbID, string username) : base(dbID, username)
{
     Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationContext>());
     Database.Initialize(true);

}
```

However, even when I have this initializer set up, I still get the error:

> **"The model backing the "ApplicationContext" has changed since the database was created. Consider using code first migrations to update
>   the database"**

some other things to note:

1. I have tried setting `AutomicMigrationsEnabled = false` as well as `true` in my    Migrations config file.
2. I have tried with and without forcing initialization

Anybody run into the same issue or have any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I was able to look through the source code for System.Data.entity here:
https://github.com/hallco978/entityframework/tree/master/src/EntityFramework

It turns out I needed to outright delete my Migrations/Configuration.cs file to prevent the error. It doesn't matter what the settings are within that configuration file.

I know get a problem because I can't drop the database if I'm using it. Does anyone know if the DeleteDatabase actually means drop the entire database or just the tables the model created?

Comment: I am sure, and actually the error message has DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in the stack trace.

Comment: can you put a debug there and test it ?

Comment: Do you have the necessary rights to drop and create the database? Also, I like to set my initializer in the STATIC constructor, but I doubt that's your issue. Show the complete stack trace.

Comment: OK, now I see this is really a [duplicate issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430502/dropcreatedatabaseifmodelchanges-ef6-results-in-system-invalidoperationexception). You should use either initializers or migrations to manage your model changes but not both. As soon as you have data you care about switch your initializer to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.